# Multiple INNER JOINs in a Rails has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :gallery_tags, :foreign_key => :gallery_id
end

class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :image
  has_many :gallery_tags, :through => :image, :source => :gallery_tags
end


class GalleryTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  belongs_to :tag
end

class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :images
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :gallery_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :gallery_tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :galleries
end
```

I'd like to be able to do

```
User.find(1).bookmarked_tags
```

and retrieve all tags associated with all of the user's bookmarked images via the galleries associated with the images. Tags are associated with galleries.

The query would end up looking like this:

```
SELECT
  tags.*
FROM
  tags
  INNER JOIN gallery_tags ON gallery_tags.tag_id = tags.id
  INNER JOIN images ON gallery_tags.gallery_id = images.gallery_id
  INNER JOIN bookmarks ON images.id = bookmarks.image_id
WHERE
  bookmarks.user_id = 1
GROUP BY
  tags.id;
```

I've tried adding

```
has_many :tags, :through => :gallery_tags, :foreign_key => :gallery_id
```

to Image, which causes Image.find(34).tags to result in

```
SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `gallery_tags` ON `tags`.id = `gallery_tags`.tag_id WHERE ((`gallery_tags`.gallery_id = 34))
```

(it's not using the image's gallery_id in the query), and then I've tried adding

```
has_many :bookmarked_tags, :through => :bookmarked_images, :source => :tags
```

to User, which causes User.find(1).bookmarked_tags to result in

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationMacroError: Invalid
>   source reflection macro :has_many :through for has_many
>   :bookmarked_tags, :through => :bookmarked_images.  Use :source to
>   specify the source reflection.

So: how can I get Rails to run the query I posted with User.find(1).bookmarked_tags?

Answer (score 4):

there are two solutions

**First Solution**:

Create a view inside your database that acts like a join table:

```
CREATE VIEW user_bookmarks_tags (
  SELECT
    bookmarks.user_id AS user_id  
    gallery_tags.tag_id AS tag_id
  FROM
    gallery_tags
    INNER JOIN images ON gallery_tags.gallery_id = images.gallery_id
    INNER JOIN bookmarks ON images.id = bookmarks.image_id
  GROUP BY
    user_id, tag_id
)
```

(you can do this inside a migration)
This view acts like a "table" with the columns `user_id | tag_id`

Now we can adapt our models using `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :galleries

  # we use our magic (view) join table here!
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, :join_table => :user_bookmarks_tags
end
```

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  # we use our magic (view) join table here
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :user_bookmarks_tags
end
```

Now you can do: `User.find(1).tags` or `Tag.find(1).users` :)

---

**Second Solution**

Do the join manually without a view:

define the missing relations (needed for the automated joins foreign_key lookup):

**tag.rb**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :gallery_tags
end
```

**gallery_tag.rb**

```
class GalleryTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gallery
  belongs_to :tag
  # new:
  has_many :images, :through => :gallery
end
```

Now we can add a `bookmarked_tags` method to our **user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecordBase
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :galleries

  def bookmarked_tags
    Tag.joins(:gallery_tags => {:images => :bookmarks}).where('bookmarks.user_id = ?', self.id).group('tags.id')
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, interesting. I figured a method would be necessary, but I'd never used Arel's .joins. Thanks, this works (I went with the second solution).